# Selenium (chromedriver) working on local machine but not on Ubuntu Server

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, ubuntu-18.04, mod-security2

I've successfully built and tested a selenium script (using python and chromedriver) that logs into my wordpress sites. The app runs flawlessly on my local machine. However, since deploying it to an Ubuntu server my script triggers a mod_security rule and blocks me from logging into my wordpress sites.

Does this have to do with cookies or the fact that its running on a server?

Any help would be appreciated. [Mod_security Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZNzk.png)

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    import time
    import os  
    import shutil 
    import smtplib
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
    from email import encoders
    from dashboard.models import Site 
    import glob



    def Backup():


        prefs = {
            'download.default_directory': r"/home/landon/app/static/dashboard/backups",
            # 'download.default_directory': r"/Users/landonroddenberry/Documents/appThree/SITERACK_1.0/dashboard/static/dashboard/backups",  #### USE only for local testing and devs #####  
            'download.prompt_for_download': False,
            'download.extensions_to_open': 'xml',
            'safebrowsing.enabled': True
        }

        chrome_path = r"/usr/bin/chromedriver"
        # chrome_path = r"/Users/landonroddenberry/Documents/chromedriver"  #### USE only for local testing and devs ##### 
        WINDOW_SIZE = "1920,1080"

        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_experimental_option('prefs',prefs)
        options.add_argument("start-maximized")
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        # options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
        options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
        options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)
        options.add_argument("--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection")
        options.add_argument("safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist")


        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path, options=options)

        logLink = "/wp-login.php"
        AdminLink = "/wp-admin/"
        page = "export.php/"
        p_col = "https://"
        sites = Site.objects.filter(active=True)


        for site in sites:

            print('')
            print('now backing up ' + site.webUrl)

            MainLink = (p_col + site.webUrl + AdminLink)
            loginLink = (p_col + site.webUrl + logLink)
            driver.get(loginLink)
            time.sleep(5)
            try:
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/form/div[3]/a[1]').click()
                time.sleep(3)

            except:
                print("no button to click")


            try:
                user_name_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="user_login"]')
                user_name_elem.clear()
                time.sleep(2)
                user_name_elem.send_keys(site.u_admin)
                time.sleep(2)
                passworword_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="user_pass"]')
                time.sleep(2)
                passworword_elem.clear()
                passworword_elem.send_keys(site.p_admin)
                time.sleep(3)
                passworword_elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
                time.sleep(5)
                driver.save_screenshot('Backup_Conflict_' + site.webUrl + '.png') ##### USED FOR DEBUGGING #######
                print('done logging-in')
                time.sleep(10)

            except:
                driver.save_screenshot('Backup_Conflict_' + site.webUrl + '.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the same chromedriver for both windows and linux OS, ten it will not work, the chromedriver is seprate for all the OS's .

Try downloading the chromedriver for linux OS.

Hope this helps.